# Practical difference between int and char

Tags: c

I have to analyse the output of these code fragments:

```
int x, y;
x = 200; y = 100;
x = x+y; y = x-y; x = x-y;
printf ("%d %d\n", x, y);

char x, y;
x = 200; y = 100;
x = x+y; y = x-y; x = x-y;
printf ("%d %d\n", x, y);
```

So, I know now that `int` stands for integer and `char` for character; I've read about the differences and if I put in the `printf` the `%d`, it returns in the form of digits, and `%c`, in the form of a character.

The ASCII character code for `'A'` is 65 for example, but why does the second function print `100 -56`, instead of `100 200`?

Comment: Your `char` isn't unsigned by default. Thus, it wraps around.

Comment: A C char is 8 bits, so 127 is the largest positive number you can have.

Comment: To elaborate, it can be signed or unsigned, and which one `char` itself is varies by implementation. You have to use a specific type if you want that on every implementation. Other types, such as `int`, default to `signed`.

Comment: Nice! Swap without a temp variable.

Comment: @BrettDuncavage, The problem is that it doesn't always work.

Comment: @HotLicks, Technically, a `char` is `CHAR_BIT` bits.

Comment: @BrettDuncavage Not so nice since it produces undefined behavior for many values. There are alternatives that don't, e.g., using exclusive-or.

Comment: @chris - Yeah, `char` has historically had an unstable definition, and C must still (sort of) accommodate (now largely extinct) hardware that has different-sized "bytes".  So anything you say about `char` comes with a bucket-load of caveats.

Comment: @JimBalter ah, yes that's true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the platform used in the question, the type `char` seems to be 1 byte (8 bits) size and is a signed type with 1 sign bit and 7 value bits (and using 2's complement arithmetic).  It stores values from -128 to 127. So, this is what's happening to `x` and `y`:

```
x = 200 => x takes value -56
y = 100 => y takes value 100
x = x+y => x takes value 44
y = x-y => y takes value -56
x = x-y => x takes value 100
```

Comment: Why not -127 to 128? 
btw, thank you for your clarification, makes sense now.

Comment: @Souza, Use the leftmost bit as the sign bit and keep adding 1 on paper. That's not guaranteed by C (only a range of [-127,127] is guaranteed for `signed char`), but that's what is really common today. The term to look for is two's complement.

Comment: chars aren't necessarily 8 bits, no are they necessarily signed. It would be better if your answer were prefixed with "Apparently, in the C environment you are using, ..."

Answer (score 9):

C has a variety of integer types: `char` (at least 8 bits), `short` (at least 16 bits), `int` (at least 16 bits), `long` (at least 32 bits). There are `unsigned` varieties of those. If you assign a value that is too large to a plain type, the results are undefined (you should never do that, the compiler may assume you never do, and not check at all). In the `unsigned` case, they "wrap around". But note that the sizes are **not guaranteed**, just their minimal sizes. There have been machines in which all were 32 bits wide.

Comment: @chris That has nothing to do with this answer. A `char` can be 32 bits wide and `sizeof(char)` is *still* 1.

Comment: @JimBalter, Yeah, I was just thinking about that. Even though I know it's not true, my mind rushed to one byte being eight bits.