# How does Python convert data types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting

So as the title says how does converting data types work? For example in Python, when you take an intger or floating number and turn it into a string. What's going on behind the scenes that does this kind of conversion. My hypothesis was that it reads the actual bytes and then goes into memory and makes a new variable that's a string.

Comment: Huh? Yes, new objects are created by all type constructors, e.g. `list`, `dict`, `str`, `int`, `float`. I don't know what you mean by "reads the actual bytes". A new *object* will be created, a new variable may not be, e.g. `a = 10; a = str(a)` doesn't create a new variable, but it does create a new object

Comment: It's literally magic.

Comment: Are you talking about how Python converts int to string? You can check out below URL first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241364/difference-between-char-and-int-when-declaring-character

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am asking how the function str() works.

Comment: @Pushk1n the function `str` will call whatever `type(my_object).__str__` is.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Could you elaborate a bit more on the process the function does to convert it to a string.

Comment: @Pushk1n is your questions **specifically** about `int` -> `str`?

Comment: @Pushk1n Every type has a `__str__` method, and it's responsible for figuring out how those values should be represented as strings.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes! How does the function know that if I type str(100) to return "100". How does it figure it out?

Comment: @Pushk1n the source code is right [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L1582). It is a built-in type, so it is implemented in C.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you, that's what I was looking for. I couldn't find it on the python documentation.

Comment: The documentation for the `__str__` method of `int` would seem to be recursive (although I'm sure it's just handled in `str` instead)—it returns `str(self)`.

Comment: @Shule yeah, so `int.__str__` returns a `<slot wrapper>` object, which essentially wraps a function implemented in C.

Comment: The following Q/A about finding out how the internals of such work might relate to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608587/finding-the-source-code-for-built-in-python-functions

Answer (score -1):

I am sharing idea and then you can extend it more :

There is no limit to how long an integer value can be but depends on amount of memory your system has, but beyond that an integer can be as long as you need it to be.

[Strings can be prepended to an integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn1sG.png)

Code : print(0x10)
Output : 16

Code : print(0b10)
Output : 2

Comment: 1) 0x is not a string 2) doesn't really answer the question