# If char can store a number in C++, why do we need int?

Tags: c++, char, int

The `char` data type can store numbers, characters, and symbols, so what is the need for the `int` data type?

```
char = '2';
```

I have knowledge of use of `int`, but I want to know the conceptual part to describe it fundamentally.

Comment: How big of a number can a char hold?

Comment: Here's a helpful post for you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241364/difference-between-char-and-int-when-declaring-character

Comment: ``char`` is 8-bit so it cannot hold number greater than 8-bit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be

Comment: Maybe you should try to store the number `256` in your `char` variable and try to print it.

Comment: Fun Fact: '2' probably doesn't equal 2.

Comment: Intriguing question (+1). I'd turn it around: why do we need `char`? Note that `'2'` is an `int` type in C.

Comment: @user4581301: Actually it *can't* equal 2. The reason is subtle. The characters `'0'` to `'9'` need to be contiguous, and none of them can be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, `int` can hold larger numbers than `char`. In current, widely available architectures, `int` is 32-bit, while `char` is 8-bit. Furthermore, it is implementation defined that a `char` is signed or unsigned.

On these architectures `int` can hold numbers between -2147483648 and 2147483647, while a (signed) `char` can hold numbers between -128 and 127.