# If char and int differ only in the number of bits, why are they different when printing?

Tags: c++, char

In [Difference between char and int when declaring character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241364/), the accepted answer says that the difference is the size in bits. Although, MicroVirus answer says:

> it plays the role of a character in a string, certainly historically. When seen like this, the value of a char maps to a specified character, for instance via the ASCII encoding, but it can also be used with multi-byte encodings (one or more chars together map to one character).

Based on those answers: In the code below, why is the output not the same (since it's just a difference in bits)? What is the mechanism that makes each type print a different "character"?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = 65;
    char b = 65;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    //output :
    //65
    //A
}
```

Comment: They call different overloads of `operator<<`

Comment: Because there's a different implementation for those different types how these are represented as text. If you want to see the `char` value as a number, you can do as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout/19562163#19562163).

Comment: Different types can have difference in what they're intended to mean and how they're handled, beyond just being difference in number of bytes.

Comment: The size of `char` and size of `int` are defined in terms of range.  A character type can be 512 bits, as long as it can support the range for `char`.  Similarly, an `int` type needs to have a minimum quantity of **bytes** to support the required range; the `int` can be larger than that.

Comment: If you need *specific* bit widths, you are encouraged to use the `u*_t` types, such as `uint8_t` or `uint32_t`; there are also bit width types for signed integers.

Comment: *"the accepted answer says that the difference is the size in bits"* vs. *"since it's just a difference in bits"* -- you added a misleading word. The difference is the size, but it's not *just* a difference in size. There is also a difference in semantics (a `char` represents a character, while an `int` represents an integer). Similarly, the word "only" in your title is an added misleading word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char` may be treated as containing a numeric value and when a `char` is treated such it indeed differs from an `int` by its size -- it is smaller, typically a byte.

However, `int` and `char` are still *different types* and since C++ is a statically typed language, types matter. A variable's type can affect the behavior of programs, not just a variable's value. In the case in your question the two variables are printed differently because the operator `<<` is overloaded; it treats `int` and `char` differently.