# Why do I get 56 and 54 as an output instead of the expected 6 and 8?

Tags: c++

I tried this in many ways and it seems simple enough for this problem not to happen. Where did the 54 and 56 come from when I assigned the value 6 and 8?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = '6', y = '8';
    while(1){
        cout << "7" << endl;
        cout <<  y  << endl; 
        y += 1;
        cout << "7" << endl;
        cout <<  x  << endl; 
        x -= 1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between the number 6 and the character literal `'6'`? Take a look at an ASCII chart.

Comment: What do your learning material say about the different basic types, like `int`, `double` or **`char`**?

Comment: So you started studying C++ with bad habits. [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: "Where did the 54 and 56 come from when I assigned the value 6 and 8?" They came from when you assigned 54, by using `'6'` to mean the integer value 54, and 56, by using `'8'` to mean the integer value 56. Notice how the compiler **did not complain** about assigning something inside quotes to an integer? As an experiment, try using e.g. `int x = 'a';`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I dont think any of those dupes relate to this question. I imagine there might be a dupe out there, but none of these are to do with assigning one type to another and printing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between char and int when declaring character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241364/difference-between-char-and-int-when-declaring-character)

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I tried my best to find the closest thing I could. I don't regularly browse c or c++ tags (although I can use those languages) so I don't have a canonical set handy; but this is such a "classic" issue that there has got to be a canonical for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c-or-c)

Answer (score 3):

you need to be aware of types. You have

```
int x = '6';
```

this says

> The variable x, of type `int` (an integer) is equal to the value of the `char` type character 6.

If you look at an [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com/) you will see that the integer value for the char `'6'` is actually **54** which is the number you are getting. If you use the correct type:

```
char x = '6';
```

Then when you give it to `std::cout` you will get the right output.