# changing the declaration from char to int, made output different

Tags: c++

In the code below, when I change the declaration of "isuit" from "char" to "int", the result differ.
I thought int and char is the same in the essense, so I cannot figure out why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int     n, irank;
    int cards[4][13] = {};
    char    isuit;
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> isuit >> irank;
        switch (isuit)
        {
            case 'S':
                cards[0][irank - 1]++;
                break;
            case 'H':
                cards[1][irank - 1]++;
                break;
            case 'C':
                cards[2][irank - 1]++;
                break;
            case 'D':
                cards[3][irank - 1]++;
                break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
            if (!cards[i][j]) {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        cout << "S" << " " << j + 1 << endl;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        cout << "H" << " " << j + 1 << endl;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        cout << "C" << " " << j + 1 << endl;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        cout << "D" << " " << j + 1 << endl;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example input:

> 47
> S 10
> S 11
> S 12
> S 13
> H 1
> H 2
> S 6
> S 7
> S 8
> S 9
> H 6
> H 8
> H 9
> H 10
> H 11
> H 4
> H 5
> S 2
> S 3
> S 4
> S 5
> H 12
> H 13
> C 1
> C 2
> D 1
> D 2
> D 3
> D 4
> D 5
> D 6
> D 7
> C 3
> C 4
> C 5
> C 6
> C 7
> C 8
> C 9
> C 10
> C 11
> C 13
> D 9
> D 10
> D 11
> D 12
> D 13

output when char:

> S 1
> H 3
> H 7
> C 12
> D 8

output when int:

> S 1
> S 2
> S 3
> S 4
> S 5
> S 6
> S 7
> S 8
> S 9
> S 10
> S 11
> S 12
> S 13
> H 1
> H 2
> H 3
> H 4
> H 5
> H 6
> H 7
> H 8
> H 9
> H 10
> H 11
> H 12
> H 13
> C 1
> C 2
> C 3
> C 4
> C 5
> C 6
> C 7
> C 8
> C 9
> C 10
> C 11
> C 12
> C 13
> D 1
> D 2
> D 3
> D 4
> D 5
> D 6
> D 7
> D 8
> D 9
> D 10
> D 11
> D 12
> D 13

Comment: char and int are two different types. Char is always 1 byte, while the size of an int may differ by compiler. For most modern desktop compilers, it is 4 bytes (32 bits).

Comment: And `'1'` and `1` have different values.

Comment: Unfortunately, when dealing with formatted I/O, `char` does not refer to a number, it refers to a character, despite being "the same thing" as an int under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of datatypes like icecream where you can choose size and flavor.

For flavors you have two choices, signed and unsigned.

For sizes, you have a range from 1 byte to 8 bytes. People refer to these as uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t.... etc.

So the difference between int and char is its 'size' and 'signed or unsignedness'. Google datatypes for more info regarding these two differences.

> Note, there is even more complexity in breaking 'how' each datatype is interpreted when it comes to byte encoding and endianess... Lets ignore that for now.

Here are some resources discussing the difference between char and int

- [Difference between char and int when declaring character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241364/difference-between-char-and-int-when-declaring-character/37241654)
- [Practical difference between int and char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869931/practical-difference-between-int-and-char)

In addition, when we think of characters and numbers they are two completetly different things in our brains. But in computers they are the similar. Like the 'yes, but actually no meme'.

> 1 != '1'
> [image: ASCII Table]

'1' is encoded as interpreted by the computer as the integer value 49. So really everything is interpreted as a number, even characters! It may help to think of it as: "Everything is a number, because everything is a series of bits. And as we know, bits are just binary numbers." ==> Everything is a number!

No back to your problem. You are telling the computer to interpret the std::cin value very differently. Remember 1 != '1'

- Int ==> A number                         (1)
- Char ==> ASCII table interpretation      ('1')

Answer (score 1):

PMF gives you a little info, but it's not sufficient. It has to do with the input method.

```
char ch;
cin >> ch;
```

and

```
int a;
cin >> a;
```

Do NOT do the same thing. When doing a cin to a character, the computer will grab a single character and copy it into your character directly. When it does an int, cin will grab a sequence of digits and then do a conversion of those characters into an int. In effect, it's the same as grabbing a string and then doing `std::stoi(those chars)`.

So if you do:

```
char ch;
cin >> ch;
```

And your input has a 1, then you get the ASCII representation of the character '1' into your character. This is NOT the same as an integer 1.

https://www.asciitable.com

That is, you get 49, but when printed as a character, it prints '1'.

Comment: Thank you very much. It became very clear.

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
cin >> isuit >> irank;
```

`isuit` can only read text input if it is `char`. If it is `int`, it expects digits (in your case, ASCII representation of the letters).

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful answer.

Comment: @ktakehi The way to say "thank you" on StackOverflow" is upvote.

Comment: I haven't got enough reputation for upvoting.